# Why is the 'src' attribute allowed to link to scripts from external domains, and XmlHtppRequests not?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cors

I have read several answers on StackOverflow regarding same-origin policy, but I don't seem to graps the essential part.

In all tags that use the `src` attribute, like `<script>` and `<img>`, you are allowed to use external resources (from another domain).

Why is this allowed, but with a XMLHttpRequest (e.g. AJAX calls) it is not. I do not seem to graps why the latter is more dangerous.

I mean, you could also have malicious code in an external source like: 
`<script src="http://example.com/malicious_script.js"></script>`

Comment: Interesting to read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Cross-origin_network_access although doesn't answer question directly.

Comment: You are allowed to use them, but you are not allowed to inspect them and access their contents programmatically. The only thing you can do is *execute* the scripts and *show* the images. You can even send arbitrary XMLHttpRequests to other domains (using the users credentials for them), you just are not allowed to access the results.

Answer (score 1):

The same-origin policy aims to protect the remote server's data from an unknown client, not to protect the client from malicious code from the server. `<script>` tags do not allow the client to make requests other than GETs or to obtain data that is not explicitly exposed by the server in a valid JavaScript file.